# BASH Script syntax error near unexpected token ';;'

Tags: bash

Trying to run this simple script but no matter what I do I get the same error, really have no idea what the problem is.

This is it:

```
    usr/local/bin/bash
clear
printf "\n\t\Menu Calcular "
printf "\n\t1.) Factorial de n "
printf "\n\t2.) e^x usando expansion de Taylor "
printf "\n\t3.) pi usando serie "
printf "\n option = "
read option
case $option in

        1)
                i=0
                fact=1
                echo "Entre un numero entero n = "
                read n
                while [ i<=n ]; do
                 let fact = $fact * $i
                echo "El factorial de n = "; echo $fact
        ;;

        *)
                clear;
                echo " I mean welp "
                ;;
esac
```

Error is syntax error near unexpected token ';;' in line 19
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can't close the case alternative with `;;` until you close the `while` with `done`. Didn't https://shellcheck.net tell you that?

Comment: the [tag:bash] tag information asks you to use https://shellcheck.net *before* you ask about your script question here. It's easy and it usually catches simple errors, saving your time and the time of everyone who volunteers here. This seemed like a good moment to remind you of that request. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help while`:

```
while: while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
```

You forgot the `done`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not ending your while loop.  After your line:

```
echo "El factorial de n = "; echo $fact
```

add a new line ending the loop like:

```
done
```